# CentOS 5.5 , Apache2.2, PHP 5.2.14, Fastcgi 2.2-4 and 5xx Errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, centos5, mod-fastcgi

I am running the version of softwares mentioned in subject. Apache was installed from standard centos repo, fastcgi was install from http://centos.karan.org/kbsingh-CentOS-Extras.repo and PHp was manually compiled and install to /usr/local/php5-fastcgi.

I keep getting 5xx Server errors when i try to visit a url such as http://vantagefx.com/affiliate/merchants/ , (and i am not using suexec btw).

**vhost**

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com


    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All


            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

    </Directory>



    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                <Directory /var/www/html/php530-files/>
                          Options +ExecCGI
                          AllowOverride All
                          AddHandler fcgid-script .php
                          FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter .php

                          Order allow,deny
                          Allow from all
                </Directory>
      </IfModule>
```

**/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter**

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/local/php5-fcgi/bin/php -c /etc/php.ini
```

**error log**

```
[Wed Sep 08 02:39:25 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2319) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:30 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:31 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:32 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:33 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:33 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2340) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:33 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2335) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:33 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2334) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:37 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2341) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:42 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
 [Wed Sep 08 02:39:43 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
[Wed Sep 08 02:39:44 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
[Wed Sep 08 02:39:45 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
[Wed Sep 08 02:39:45 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2364) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
[Wed Sep 08 02:39:45 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php(2359) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), r5
```

and:

```
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:05 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:06 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:07 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:16 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:17 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:18 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:19 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:28 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:29 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:30 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:31 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:35 2010] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/html/affiliate/phpinfo.php
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:40 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:41 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:42 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:43 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:52 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:53 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:54 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:49:55 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Wed Sep 08 09:50:05 2010] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
```

and if i manually execute the code of

```
/usr/local/php5-fcgi/bin/php /var/www/html/php530-files/scripts/imp.php
```

it executes just fine, no errors, no warnings, no notices.

[EDIT]

**PHP Processes**

```
ps aux | grep php
apache   22494  1.5  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:16   0:00 [php] <defunct>
root     22500  0.0  0.0  61168   728 pts/0    S+   08:16   0:00 grep php
```

I also created a phpinfo.php inside php530-files dir and tried accessing that, still no luck, 503 Service Unavailable and log was:

```
[Wed Sep 08 08:27:45 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/phpinfo.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
[Wed Sep 08 08:27:46 2010] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/php530-files/phpinfo.php with wrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
```

See, this process did not terminate due to any communication error or such but i still get 5xx errors.

**Permissions**

```
[root@www php530-files]# ls -l
total 35604
drwxrwxr-x  3 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 accounts
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:42 affiliates
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 api
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil      247 Sep  8 03:41 CHANGELOG.txt
drwxrwxr-x 11 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 include
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil     2203 Sep  8 03:41 index.html
drwxrwxr-x  9 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 install
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil      185 Sep  8 03:42 INSTALL.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil     7643 Sep  8 03:41 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 merchants
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil 36340881 Sep  8 03:41 pap_4.5.19.2.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 apache vfx_affil       20 Sep  8 08:23 phpinfo.php
drwxrwxr-x 52 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:42 plugins
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil     1008 Sep  8 03:41 README.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:41 samples_tests
drwxrwxr-x  3 apache vfx_affil     4096 Sep  8 03:50 scripts
-rw-r--r--  1 apache vfx_affil       31 Sep  8 08:27 test.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache vfx_affil      371 Sep  8 03:41 UPDATE.txt
[root@www affiliate]# ls -l /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache vfx_affil 203 Sep  8 03:39 php-fcgi-starter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
In my case i was using wrong php binary in /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter, it should have been php-cgi.

Works like a charm with:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_CGI=/usr/local/php5-fcgi/bin/php-cgi
PHP_INI=/etc/php-fastcgi.ini
export PHP_FCGI_TIMEOUT=1200
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=10
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
exec $PHP_CGI -c $PHP_INI
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter` executable, and is it and the directory it's in owned by the web server user?

Comment: ls -l /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter
-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache vfx_affil 203 Sep  8 03:39 /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter

So Yes

Comment: also see:ps aux | grep php
apache   22494  1.5  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    08:16   0:00 [php] <defunct>
root     22500  0.0  0.0  61168   728 pts/0    S+   08:16   0:00 grep php